# how to populate multiple access tables from visual studio

Tags: vb.net, oledb

Apologies in advance - I am a newbie to visual studio( and programming in general)

I am trying to populate two access tables landlord and property using the following code - But I keep getting

> " Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement."

ANY Suggestions ?  Here's the code:

```
Dim aConnection As OleDbConnection
Dim aCommand As OleDbCommand
Dim aConnectionString, aQuery As String
Dim Username As String = txtUsername.Text
Dim Pword As String = TextBox2.Text
Dim EmailDetails As String = TextBox9.Text
Dim Question As String = DropDownList2.Text
Dim Answer As String = TextBox4.Text

aConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = " _
& Server.MapPath("AppData/RMT.accdb")
aConnection = New OleDbConnection(aConnectionString)
aConnection.Open()
aQuery = "Insert Into Landlord (Username, email, Security_Question, Security_Answer, Pword, Status) Values ('" & Username & "','" & EmailDetails & "','" & Question & "','" & Answer & "', '" & Pword & "','pending')Into Property Values (26,46,'marysway','MarysRd','Marysville','Cork North')"
aCommand = New OleDbCommand(aQuery, aConnection)
aCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

aConnection.Close()
```

Comment: `Pword & "','pending')Into Property Values` - looks strange, but 'im not an access-expert. As a general tip: Use OleDBParameters with your OleDBCommand. It will make your code much easier to read and less error prone (try inserting a date ;) )

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the ADO.NET provider for Microsoft Access supports multiple insert statement in the same query string. However, just to check, you could try to write

```
aQuery = "Insert Into Landlord (Username, email, Security_Question, Security_Answer, " & _ 
         "Pword, Status) Values ('" & Username & "','" & EmailDetails & "','" & _
         Question & "','" & Answer & "', '" & Pword & "','pending');" & _
         "Insert Into Property Values (26,46,'marysway','MarysRd','Marysville','Cork North')"
```

Note the semicolon between the first INSERT statement and the second one (by the way, the second INSERT keyword was missing in your original code)

Said that, I recommend to use ALWAYS the parameter collection of the OleDbCommand when building query text to pass to the database engine.
This will avoid problems with text parsing (a single quote in your input text breaks everything), but also, you don't expose your code to [Sql Injection Attacks](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)

```
Using aConnection = New OleDbConnection(aConnectionString)
    aConnection.Open()

    aQuery = "Insert Into Landlord (Username, email, Security_Question, " + 
             "Security_Answer, Pword, Status) Values (?, ?, ?,?,?,'pending')"
    aCommand = New OleDbCommand(aQuery, aConnection)
    aCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr", Username)
    aCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", EmailDetails)
    aCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qst", Question)
    aCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ans", Answer)
    aCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", Pword)
    aCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    aQuery = "Insert Into Property Values (26,46,'marysway','MarysRd','Marysville','Cork North')"
    aCommand = New OleDbCommand(aQuery, aConnection)
    aCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Using
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - This is giving me a message saying "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement" - Back to the drawing board I think

Comment: Are you referring the the double insert statement or at the second example with the separated statements? In this second case, is the first insert or the second one that fails?

Comment: Actually Steve - The 2nd option worked perfectly, Many Thanks for your help!

Comment: As I have supposed. The ADO.NET driver for Microsoft Access cannot handle multiple statement in the same query. I was certain of that for Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0, not sure per ACE but it seems the same. You should use separate statements.